# Change Notification Layout When using Onesignal in android

Tags: android, onesignal

I am new to push notification, and I use OneSignal to send messages. But I want to change its notification layout in anroid so it become Right To Left. But I can not find anything regards that in OneSignal documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Android devices automatically support RTL notifications as a device-level setting starting in Android 4.2. It is not a setting on the notification itself.

You can learn more about Android's RTL support on the official Android developer blog here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html